# Access level on VB.NET

Tags: database, vb.net

I have created a system and im new to vb.net. It is working fine. The problem is, I need to restrict the main page from 1.) Users and 2.) Admin.

For example, After logging in, Admin will proceed to the main page 
 And if users logs in, they will be directed to a different page

I'm still new to vb.net (like 6 weeks ago) and i am using microsoft access as my database. A lot of code I find online is very complex and technical. I just need simple vb.net code

Any help will be appreciated, thank you!!
i have posted my code for my login form, so you guys can further understand my coding:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim loginerror As String
    Public Function login()
    Dim DBconn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim user As New ADODB.Recordset

    Dim Username As String
    Dim userDB As String
    Dim passDB As String

    Dim UserFound As Boolean

    DBconn.Open("Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
                "Data Source = '" & Application.StartupPath & "\LoginDB.mdb'")

    user.Open("UserTable", DBconn, ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic, ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockOptimistic)

    UserFound = False
    login = False
    Username = "Username = '" & txtuser.Text & "'" '

    Do
        user.Find(Username)
        If user.BOF = False And user.EOF = False Then
            userDB = user.Fields("Username").Value.ToString

            passDB = user.Fields("Password").Value.ToString

            If userDB <> txtuser.Text Then
                user.MoveNext()
            Else
                UserFound = True
                If passDB = txtpass.Text Then
                    user.Close()
                    DBconn.Close()
                    Return True
                Else
                    loginerror = "Invalid Password"
                    user.Close()
                    DBconn.Close()
                    Return False
                End If
            End If
        Else
            loginerror = "Invalid Username"
            user.Close()
            DBconn.Close()
            Return False
        End If
    Loop Until UserFound = True
    user.Close()
    DBconn.Close()
    Return False


End Function


Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If login() = True Then
        Welcome.Show()
        Me.Close()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show(loginerror, "Login Message")
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    AcceptButton = Button1
    Me.Show()
    Application.DoEvents()
    txtuser.Focus()
End Sub

Private Sub txtpass_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtpass.TextChanged

End Sub

Private Sub Label2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Label2.Click

End Sub

Private Sub txtuser_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtuser.TextChanged

End Sub

Private Sub Label1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click

End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click

End Sub

Private Sub Label3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Label3.Click

End Sub

End Class
```

Just in case here is my coding for my main form:

```
Public Class Mainform
Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    Select MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to exit?", "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
        Case Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes
        Case Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No
            e.Cancel = True
    End Select

End Sub

Private Sub Mainform_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.WorkTableAdapter.Fill(Me.LoginDBDataSet.Work)

    Me.AssetTableAdapter.Fill(Me.LoginDBDataSet.Asset)

    Me.HistoryTableAdapter.Fill(Me.LoginDBDataSet.History)

    Me.InventoryTableAdapter.Fill(Me.LoginDBDataSet.Inventory)

    Me.Equipment1TableAdapter.Fill(Me.LoginDBDataSet.Equipment1)


End Sub
Private Sub mainform_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Escape Then Me.Close()

End Sub

Private Sub Equipment1BindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Equipment1BindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click
    Me.Validate()
    Me.Equipment1BindingSource.EndEdit()
    Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.LoginDBDataSet)

End Sub

Private Sub ToolStripButton1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ToolStripButton1.Click
    Mainform_Load(Me, New System.EventArgs)
End Sub

Private Sub ToolStripButton2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ToolStripButton2.Click
    Form1.Show()
    Me.Dispose()
    Me.Close()

End Sub

Private Sub TabPage1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TabPage1.Click

End Sub

Private Sub IDLabel_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

End Sub

Private Sub TabPage5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TabPage5.Click

End Sub

Private Sub Equipment_NameTextBox_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

End Sub

Private Sub HistoryDataGridView_CellContentClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs)

End Sub

Private Sub InventoryDataGridView_CellContentClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs)

End Sub

Private Sub TabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TabControl1.SelectedIndexChanged

End Sub

Private Sub Machine_IDTextBox_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

End Sub

Private Sub _WO_CompletedLabel_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

End Sub

Private Sub _WO_CompletedCheckBox_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

End Sub

Private Sub _WO_CompletedCheckBox_CheckedChanged_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

End Sub

Private Sub Machine_IDTextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Machine_IDTextBox1.TextChanged

End Sub

Private Sub _WO_CompletedCheckBox_CheckedChanged_2(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles _WO_CompletedCheckBox.CheckedChanged

End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to determine if the user is administrator or not (usually your user table should have a role attached to the user e.g. administration, employee, etc.)

something like this when you try to log in

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
If login() = True and UserRole='Administrator' Then
    Welcome.Show()
    Me.Close()
elseif login() = True then
    WelcomeUser.Show()
    Me.Close()
Else
    MessageBox.Show(loginerror, "Login Message")
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: Yes thank you i have done what you have told me , however i keep getting the error 'UserRole' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: UserRole is just my term for maybe the value of a string in your users table.. for example your users table has a column named UserRole with values like employee, administrator, etc.. get the value of that specific user who logged in then check if he is an administrator (as stated in my sample above) then open the form for the administrator.. or open a form for a normal user if otherwise..